# windows ce 5.0 bat copy permission

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy, cmd, windows-ce

I'm trying to create a bat file to copy a dll to paste in the windows foler, the file already exists in windows but I want to print my own.

The code I have is:

```
DIR \Windows\shdoclc.dll
icacls \Windows\shdoclc.dll
ATTRIB -R -S -H \Windows\shdoclc.dll
COPY \Temp\shdoclc.dll \Windows\shdoclc.dll
pause
```

I can copy/paste it manually from windows ce, everywan, or activesync, but the command terminal doesn't work because of the file location, the file is hidden/ read only/ and a system file, the attribute command doesn't work.

and it gives me an error every time the \windows\shdolc.dll is involved, but if I change the file name or location the copy works fine.

I think it's a problem with the permision of the command prompt, don't nkow how to change it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows has that file as a [protected file](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/Q222193), so will restore it whenever it is changed.
Here's a cheat to get around that *(unfortunately, I don't have **ce** to test, only XP)*

```
COPY \Temp\shdoclc.dll %systemroot%\system32\dllcache
DEL %systemroot%\shdoclc.dll
```

This copies your version into the cache, and when the actual file is deleted, windows restores the version it has backed up in the dllcache.

Comment: windows ce is a very special type of OS, I've been trying to find the source of the backup but I haven't found it, which is why I'm trying to make a bat to copy the dll on startup.

Answer (score 0):

for some reason, the copy command doesn't let you copy over a system file. the attribute command doesn't let you change system file attribute, but the move command lets you replace a system file, so my code ends up being:

```
copy \Application\shdoclc.dll \Temp\shdoclc.dll
MOVE \Temp\shdoclc.dll \Windows\shdoclc.dll
```